# How can you recognise square numbers by looking at its prime factors?

Tags: prime-factorization, square-numbers

Also how can yo do this with cube numbers?
And the same with a cube number that is also square?
Thanks.

Comment: If I have an arbitrary integer $n = p_1^{r_1} \cdots p_m^{r_m} > 1$, what do $n^2$ and $n^3$ look like?

Comment: You can't.  You have to like at the powers of the prime factors as well.  In fact the prime factors can belong to any number so looking at the prime factores won't tell you anything.  You have to look at and only have to look at the powers of the prime factors.

Comment: Welcome, next time try provide more details about what's you are asking, how explain us your question, learn tex in our [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), see if it was asked... Courage.

Answer (score 1):

A number is square of the indices of its prime factorization are all even.

A number is a cube of the indices of its prime factorization are all multiple of $3$.

A number is both a cube and a square if the indices of its prime factorization are multiples of $6$.

Can you see why?

Comment: Thank you for this. It is a big a help. I cans see that is actually quite simple.